# How does youtube's html player load/play dash fragments

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, mpeg-dash

I have a browser extension that loads the audio only portion of a youtube video into the html player on youtube, right now the URL for the audio only portion is one big file, instead of loading the entire file I want to implement dash fragments.

I know I could completely replace the youtube player with my own and use dash.js or bitdash but I really want to interact with youtube's implementation for the most native youtube 'look and feel' and in my opinion better UX.

Right now I know that youtube's dash mpd files reside on the domain manifest.googlevideo.com and I know how to scrape the mpd url from `youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=` but what I don't know is where in the page's javascript that youtube scrapes this mpd file or where it parses it and **how it loads the dash fragments into the player**, I've tried searching various .js files on the page but because the sources are minified/obfuscated its incredibly difficult to understand.
The only thing I've found is 3 instances of the string `"dashmpd"` inside of `yts/jsbin/player-vfl8BSHQD/en_US/base.js`
My main question is how do I manually play a dash fragment with youtube's html player.
E.g. of the fragment url format `https://r7---sn-uxanug5-coxe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/id/cbd5bb673957f5ca/itag/140/source/youtube/requiressl/yes/mn/sn-uxanug5-coxe/mm/31/pl/18/mv/m/ms/au/initcwndbps/657500/ei/2GgiWqykHoXQ4wKXyLLgBg/ratebypass/yes/mime/audio%2Fmp4/otfp/1/gir/yes/clen/3595249/lmt/1509617663259919/dur/226.324/signature/70BA066760585F9F6521BADDCEAE7BF477B48918.4A74BD412DFF151B1215BF099595F3179B94D174/mt/1512204398/key/dg_yt0/beids/%5B9466593%5D/ip/123.456.123.456/ipbits/0/expire/1512226104/sparams/ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,mn,mm,pl,mv,ms,initcwndbps,ei,ratebypass,mime,otfp,gir,clen,lmt,dur/range/477676-636832`

Comment: You are aware that your IP address is visible in that url...

Comment: its not, I replaced it with a bogus ip 123.456.123.456

Comment: Good good. I wanted to point that out because I have been someone post something like this before which contained the IP.